# Lodash orderBy on nested Arrays of objects

Tags: sorting, lodash

Have an array of objects with some nested properties:

```
const sports = [{
  name: "Basketball",
  leagues: [{
     createdAt: 1
  }, {
     createdAt: 2
  }]
},{
  name: "Soccer",
  leagues: [{
     createdAt: 3
  }, {
     createdAt: 4
  }]
}]
```

To get the array of object sorted by name DESC (Z->A) (non nested property) I do:

```
const sorted = _.orderBy(sports, item => item.name, ['desc']);
```

The result is

```
[{ name: "Soccer", ... },{ name: "Basketball", ... }]
```

What I am trying to achieve is to sort this object based on its nested array of objects `leagues.createdAt` DESC (assuming 1,2,3,4 are the correct timestamps):

```
[{
  name: "Soccer",
  leagues: [{
     createdAt: 4
  }, {
     createdAt: 3
  }]
},{
  name: "Basketball",
  leagues: [{
     createdAt: 2
  }, {
     createdAt: 1
  }]
}]
```

Tried to do smth like that:

```
const sorted = _.orderBy(sports, [(item) => item.leagues[0].createdAt], ["desc"])
```

but the order is not quite right:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to map the ordered array, and sort the `leagues` using `_.orderBy()`. I'm using `_.flow()` to create a function that first sorts the entire array, and then maps and sorts the `leagues` in each object.

```js
const { flow, orderBy, map } = _

const fn = flow(
  arr => orderBy(arr, 'name', 'desc'),
  arr => map(arr,  ({ leagues, ...o }) => ({
    ...o,
    leagues: orderBy(leagues, 'createdAt', 'desc')
  }))
)

const sports = [{"name":"Basketball","leagues":[{"createdAt":1},{"createdAt":2}]},{"name":"Soccer","leagues":[{"createdAt":3},{"createdAt":4}]}]

const result = fn(sports)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: How would I modify your function to handle the inner orderBy where the array needs to be ordered by named properties, and where the array might have no values .e.g. leagues: orderBy(leagues, ['name','createdAt'], 'desc') and the leagues array may be empty i.e. []. I'm a bit stumped on how to modify it. Sigh.

Comment: Hi @JeremyW - it's pretty hard to understand what you need from the comment, and to answer it in a comment. Create a new question.